# Cutting an archway in a wall of a model of a building

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am a newbie at Blender, but love it. I am trying to create a model of a building which is to be constructed. There are several arched openings in walls. I am having a great deal of trouble being able to create these arches. I have googled but not found anything that works.

Comment: You could try the [Boolean modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans), but other then that it's hard to say without seeing screenshots of your model/topology.

Answer (score 3):

You could model the arch's shape from a plane and use [*Knife Project*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Knife_Subdivide).

[image]

- Select first the arch then the wall in *Object Mode*
- Change to *Edit Mode* and apply *Knife Project*

After that you should have a model like:

[image]

If  you want to connect the arches select them by <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd> and *Bridge Edge Loops*

Alternativley (as suggested by Gandalf3) you could use the [*Boolean Modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans).

For this technique you would need to extrude the arch like the red object here:

[image]

- Align the objects
- Add a *Boolean Modifier* to your wall, and set operation to *Difference*
- Apply the modifier

[image]

The result should look like:

[image]

Comment: Tried both methods and found the boolean modifier works best for me. Much thanks for the help.

Comment: @ken, would you mind marking this post as the answer by clicking the checkmark?