# Punching a Hole

Tags: mesh, modifiers, workflow, knife-tool

Alright, I am new to Blender, I have watched many videos explaining how to make a hole in a mesh, but all the examples use just a plane or a cube,

I am making a Helo/Jet or VTOL with props in the wings,I have the Jet Modeled and need to punch a Hole through the wings and can not seem to figure it out[image]

Above is a ScreenShot, Like I said this is my first object i have done in blender. I would like to Put a hole in each wing and one through the tale.

Comment: I've flagged this in the hope a mod will move it to blender.se - I can't really use Blender

Comment: Use the [Knife Project Tool](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html#knife-project) Or Boolean Modifier: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6321/cutting-an-archway-in-a-wall-of-a-model-of-a-building/6333#6333 for suggested reading

Comment: The site can be explored by using the search tool too: http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=cut+hole

Comment: You can use the Boolean Modifier set to "Difference" as already suggested, or use the Booltron Addon, which I find a bit more versatile than the builtin modifier, and quicker to use in most cases.

Here's a video and the link to the addon's repository:    
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxbJSUQpw7I

Comment: Anthony (OP), I think you would be better off modeling the holes than doing a boolean because your mesh is low-poly and you'll want to keep the topology clean if you plan to subsurf. Use the Mirror Modifier so you don't have to repeat the same operations on the left and right sides. Learn to use "Loop Cut" "Knife Tool" "Delete faces" "Fill faces" and you'll have the basic knowledge needed for cutting holes.  @torels Thanks for suggesting Booltron! Just installed it. Huge time-saver.

Comment: Thanks guys like i said.. really new to this, already using mirror for this model, every thing else you guys suggested went right over my head, I have seen the buttons for what your suggesting, I will do check google and see what i can figure out. and here is a link to the model on my onedrive 

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AB21864BC8446233!3089&authkey=!AFU9KALOTkzhHsY&ithint=file%2cblend

Answer (score 3):

The steps you have seen for making a hole in a flat mesh will get you 90% of the way there. Once you have the two holes on either side of your wing, simply select the vertices around the hole on both sides and use bridge edge loops to add a surface connecting the two sides. You can either search for this in the space bar menu or find it in *Mesh->Edges->Bridge Edge Loops*

[image]

You may also want to add a small bevel (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) around both ends of the hole.

[image]